# JSON-LD reverse properties for Event Rich Snippets

Tags: microdata, google-rich-snippets-tool, json-ld

I have a page which displays multiple events for one location. For Rich Snippets to work for an event the location is a mandatory field.  Rather than duplicate the location information for every event I was hoping to use a @reverse property in my JSON-LD.

However, it seems that the Structured Data Testing Tool doesn't seem to recognise my reverse property for what it is.  Is this simply a limitation of the testing tool, or have I missed something with my setup?

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context":"http://schema.org",
    "@type":"MovieTheater",
    "name":"My Movie Theatre",
    "location": "1 Here St",
    "telephone": "555 1234",
    "@reverse":{
        "location":
        [
            {
                "@type":"VisualArtsEvent",
                "name":"OCULUS",
                "startDate":"2015-03-04T12:05:00",
                "duration":"PT1H49M"
            },
            {
                "@type":"VisualArtsEvent",
                "name":"OCULUS",
                "startDate":"2015-03-19T14:00:00",
                "duration":"PT1H49M"
            },
            {
                "@type":"VisualArtsEvent",
                "name":"RoboCop",
                "startDate":"2015-03-10T15:00:00",
                "duration":"PT1H"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```